# How to redirect back to cordova application after successful payment

Tags: cordova, payment-gateway, redirect

I am using InAppBrowser to redirect to payment gateway to accept payment. But could not redirect back to the app after payment. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can achieve it directly. Alternatively, use [inappbrowser](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser) 
to open the redirection and success page (which will obviously reside on your server).

Use the exit event of inappbrowser to execute your javascript function of cordova app which internally redirects to success page.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
 let browser = window.open('https://www.payumoney.com/paybypayumoney/#/abcd1234', '_self');
     browser.addEventListener('loadstart',function(event){
      console.log(event)
      if (event["url"] == "http://localhost:3000/capture_successfull_payment") {
         browser.close()
        }
       });
```